# Geoprocessing tools fail though CRS same, prj-file ok, edit mode off, topology valid, etc

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, ring

For my layers none of the QGIS geoproccesing tools (difference, intersection, etc. all give empty attribute tables) work, though I've checked for all (?) error sources (as in the title). Then I tried to do a manual edit of my polygon-geometry (adding a ring) and this is what happend (the data is in my [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b1aujxgw3co7y74/stack_overflow_data.zip?dl=0)):
[image]

I'm using QGIS 2.10.0 on Win7

Comment: I get the same result in QGIS 2.10 Pisa. Very strange.

Comment: Thanks for trying! ..there must be something wrong with the geometry..

Comment: What kind of output are you wanting to achieve? Is it only an intersection of the 2 layers or something else?

Comment: Actually I want a difference operation with the other layer (the small blue polygons).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an issue with your "*mair_dxf*" layers. From the metadata, it reads that there's **3 features** whereas in the Attribute Table, it only reads **2 features.**

To rectify this, re-save the layer as a new shapefile. The metadata should read 2 features now, run the **Difference** tool again:

[image: Result]

Hope this helps!

---

**Edit**:

Turns out that there is an issue with QGIS 2.10 where the layers fail to be processed correctly. However, the layers work fine in **QGIS 2.8.2** and **2.12.0** where I was also able to add rings successfully:

[image: Rings added]

Comment: This was looking hopeful - but I did exactly as proposed (Metadata in new file says 2 features) - but the same result as before.. Attribute table of newly created shape is empty! ...I'd be very interested if you can reproduce the error when trying to add a ring? Could you do that for me? Many thanks!

Comment: @Kay - Weird, I cannot reproduce your error. I was able to add rings fine. I'm using QGIS 2.12, will test this on 2.10 and see if the error can be reproduced :)

Comment: @Kay - Now this is funny, I can reproduce the error in QGIS 2.10. It works perfectly fine in 2.12-0 and 2.8.2. Think it might be time to upgrade your QGIS (or downgrade!) :)

Comment: Joseph, many thanks - you saved my day (thought I'm going nuts!) However, it is very awkard that this issue wasn't noticed/looked for earlier! Would you please add this to the answer - then I will check it!

Comment: @Kay - Haha, I'm already nuts working with GIS! Edited the post, hope you got the results you're looking for :)

Comment: @Kay - Most welcome buddy :)